# Load template on click angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Have tried loading the template on click of the button but some where approach is wrong templates are not loading.

Here adding the tried plunker:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/siPDCWOWOPNwsr9JSSw8?p=preview)

Can anyone let me know where had gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is following:

You haven't called the function. you have to say cClick().

You said:-

```
<button ng-model='template' ng-click='cClick'>Click</button>
```

try this:-

```
<button ng-model='template' ng-click='cClick()'>Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you it works.. how do I hide template again on click of the same button. I tried ng-click='cClick()=!cClick()', but it is not working.

Comment: you can create one default template and one button on each template **Reset Template** which will assign that default template to $scope.

Comment: I cant do like that because I will show the template as an overlay. So everytime I will load the template 1 on click.

Comment: you can say:-

$scope.cClick = function() {
     if($scope.template)
       $scope.template = null;
    else
     $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
   }